# In Matlab, I would like to remove all the zeros in a matrix without changing the configuration of my matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to remove all zeros in a matrix. Those zeros appear at the end of each row. See example :

```
5.7327    7.1388    7.9082
6.5109    7.1689    8.1205
7.0741    6.9802    8.0936
7.4028         0    7.8214
7.4871         0         0
     0         0         0
     0         0         0
```

If I use out = out(out~=0), it gives mean a vector instead of my matrix...

For output I would like to get :

```
5.7327    7.1388    7.9082
6.5109    7.1689    8.1205
7.0741    6.9802    8.0936
7.4028              7.8214
7.4871
```

thank you for your helps

Comment: Please specify (a) a programming language (i.e. tag appropriately) and (b) what output you would expect for the above example. Please also read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for answering. I modified my post, you can see the out I would like to get.

Comment: What do you expect the content of those "empty" matrix elements to be ?  Or is this just for display purposes ?

Comment: I just don't want those zeros because I need to apply a different coefficient for each row (and so not for the zeros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab, A matrix can not have different columns with different row lengths. There are a number of things you can do and it depends on the purpose for removing the zeros:
1. replace the zeros with NaN values:

```
out(out==0)=nan;
```

2. convert the matrix to a cell array and the remove zeros from each cell:

```
outCell = mat2cell(out,ones(size(out,2),1),size(out,1))
outCell = cellfun(@(o) o=o(o~=0),outCell,'uniformoutput',false);
```

Please elaborate on the reason you want to remove the zeros

Comment: Great! Thank you. I have my matrix, I want to apply a different coefficient for each row (but not for zeros) and after I will transpose my matrix in a single vector.